# does Regex omit part of a string if it has already been matched?

Tags: python, regex, python-re

Python 3.8.2
the task at hand is simple: to match lowercase characters separated by a single underscore. So the pattern could be `r"[a-z]+_[a-z]+"`

now my issue is that I expected `re.findall()` to pair up all the following:

"ash_tonic_transit_so_kern_err_looo_"

instead of paring all the words around each underscore ('ash_tonic', 'tonic_transit', 'transit_so', ETC) I get three pairs: ['ash_tonic', 'transit_so', 'kern_err']

Does python re omit part of the string once a match has been found instead of running the search again?

```
import re
def match_lower(s):
    patternRegex = re.compile(r'[a-z]+_[a-z]+')
    mo =  patternRegex.findall(s)
    return mo



print(match_lower('ash_tonic_transit_so_kern_err_looo_'))
```

Comment: the re-module does not do partial re-matches,once you match something its off the string.

Comment: That's how *all* regex flavours would work - you've specified (simplified) `[a-z]_[a-z]` so from `a_b_c_d` it will match `a_b`, once consumed, the regex will continue *from* there.

Comment: You can use a capturing group with a negative lookbehind inside a lookahead `(?=(?<![a-z])([a-z]+_[a-z]+))` https://regex101.com/r/VW7BKW/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird Interesting, I never thought that lookbehinds/lookaheads can be nested. TIL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a positive lookahead with a capturing group to get the matches, and start the match asserting what is directly to the left is not a char a-z using a negative lookbehind.

Use [re.findall](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall) which will return the values from the capturing group.

```
(?<![a-z])(?=([a-z]+_[a-z]+))
```

**Explanation**

- `(?<![a-z])` Negative lookabehind, assert what is directly to the left is not a char a-z
- `(?=` Positive lookahead, assert what on the right is

  - `([a-z]+_[a-z]+)` Capture **group 1**, match 1+ chars a-z _ 1+ chars a-z
- `)` Close lookahead

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/PwZh7i/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/nagKfd)

```
import re
 
regex = r"(?<![a-z])(?=([a-z]+_[a-z]+))"     
test_str = "ash_tonic_transit_so_kern_err_looo_"     
print(re.findall(regex, test_str))
```

Output

```
['ash_tonic', 'tonic_transit', 'transit_so', 'so_kern', 'kern_err', 'err_looo']
```

Comment: thanks you! i see this solution works just as i want it, I haven't learnt the lookaround bits of regex but ill use your solution as a guide

Answer (score 0):

This is explicitly mentioned in [the documentation of `re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/re.html#re.findall):

> Return all *non-overlapping* matches of pattern in string, as a list of strings.

For instance, `'ash_tonic'` and `'tonic_transit'` overlap, so they won't be considered two distinct matches.

Comment: I see, any work around that? I dont see any posible re.findall() flag to modify this behivior

Comment: @veziop, well, [the lookahed/lookbehind solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64544294/4354477) looks nice